# Why unexpected token is showing?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

Can someone please check out my code & tell why I am getting an error at line 16?
See codePen - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/crazydeveloper/pen/YdzKZP)

```
calcTotal: function(type) {
    sum = 0;
    data.allItems[type].forEach(function(cur) {
        sum = sum += cur.value();
    }
)
    data.totals[type] = data.totals[type] + sum;
}
```

Comment: What is the error exactly, and what is line 16?

Comment: Please see codePen https://codepen.io/crazydeveloper/pen/YdzKZP

Comment: You should edit the relevant details into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write this (outside of an object literal) in a code block:

```
calcTotal: function(type) {
```

... should be:

```
var calcTotal = function(type) {
```

Comment: That function is in the Object, It's a method. Please see codePen https://codepen.io/crazydeveloper/pen/YdzKZP

Comment: Oh sorry, I was confused there. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @CrazyDeveloper, if you need `calcTotal` to be a method, you can declare it similar to your `addItem` method.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you're getting error, you should write

```
function calcTotal (type)
```

Or

```
calcTotal = function(type) // instead using double dot
```

Comment: the "double dot" is more commonly referred to as a colon btw